# edit index custom post type page with elementor or other

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

i have a custom post type in wordpress like book. i can edit single pages template with add single-book.php file and edit archive pages template with archive-book.php file.

i know main page of this post type (example.com/book/) is archive type.

but i want create a new page in admin panel and set book in url (like woocommerce and blog in wordpress) and edit this page with elementor and create a diffrent template. (when look example.com/book/ we see this page instead of archive page)

how can i do that? (without plugin)